# Postgres string composed only of vowels

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

How can I query my postgres database to find strings in my column "name" that are only composed of vowel characters. I am currently trying:

```
SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE aname ~* '[aeiouAEIOU]';
```

But it dosent seem to be working correctly.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work, specifically? That pattern isn't for a string containing only vowels.

Comment: I was trying SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE aname ~ '[aeiouAEIOU]'; not with the * sorry, but should this not find the strings with only vowels?

Comment: No, depending on whether Postgres needs the whole thing to match it's either only rows whose aname is a single vowel, or only rows whose aname contains a vowel anywhere. If you have a [mre] to show the issue that would be more obvious.

Comment: The anames are like augue vestibulum ante.avi, sem.mov, curabitur convallis duis.mp3 so contain spaces and .

Comment: I mean [edit] the question to show inputs and expected and actual outputs. None of those examples contain only vowels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code checks if the string contains *at least one vowel*, which is different than containing *only vowels*.

Consider, instead:

```
SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE aname ~* '^[aeiou]+$'
```

`^` and `$` delimit the begining and end of the string, so this ensures that the string contains only vowels (and at least one character).

Note that `~*` performs a case-insensitive match, so there is no need to put the upper case vowels in the character class.

You could also express this as:

```
SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE aname !~* '[^aeiou]'
```

Which phrases as: the string does not contain a character other than a vowel.